# ViewModel factory returns new instances instead of existing one

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, viewmodelfactory

I am using

```
    class MyViewModelFactory(
    private val app: Application,
    private val someClass: SomeClass,
       ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MyViewModel(application, someClass) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
  }
```

And

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, MyViewModelFactory(application, someClass)).get(
        MyViewModel::class.java
    )
```

But every time when the fragment instantiated, **new** `viewmodel` is created, instead of to return existing `viewmodel`.

Comment: That would seem to be the expected behavior. The only time that you would get an existing viewmodel is on a configuration change or if your scope of the viewmodel is bigger than the fragment (e.g., an activity-scoped viewmodel).

Comment: As I remember without factory I am getting existing viewmodel per fragment

Comment: Presumably, you changed your viewmodel scope.